# Can not trigger the p:calendar's selectListener

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

My code is as follows :

```
<p:calendar showOn="button"
                  value="#{searchMB.filledFromDate}"
                  pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" maxlength="10" id="filledFromDate"
                  converter="submittedDateConverter"
                  converterMessage="#{message.filled_date_from_is_not_a_valid_date}"
                  styleClass="calendar" selectListener="#{searchMB.test}"
                  onchange="alert('')"
                  onSelectUpdate="filledToDate_panel">
                  <f:ajax event="blur" execute="filledFromDate"
                     render="filledToDate_panel"></f:ajax>
 </p:calendar>


   public void test(DateSelectEvent event) {
       System.out.println("-------------->" + event);
    }
```

- I want to implements this **function**: 
  when I select the down-list of the Calendar , I want to invoke the `test` method right away, to put the select date to **another** Calendar input .

  If I don't add the converter . the method will be triggered.But
  after  I add a **converter** , the method `selectListener="#{searchMB.test}"` can not be triggered.I don't konw why.Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the `<f:ajax>` tag within a Primefaces component.

For many Primefaces components you can use the `<p:ajax>` tag instead however for `<p:calendar>` you can instead use a variety of different attributes to give you Ajax functionality.

From the Primefaces Guide 2.2

`OnSelectProcess` - Components to process with ajax when a date is selected (default: `@this`).

And on Ajax selection listener from the guide:

> Ajax Selection
>   Calendar supports instant ajax selection which means whenever a date is selected a server side 
>   selectListener can be invoked with an  org.primefaces.event.DateSelectEvent instance as a 
>   parameter. Optional onSelectUpdate option allows updating other component(s) on page.

```
<p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date}" onSelectUpdate="messages"
     selectListener="#{calendarBean.handleDateSelect}" />
 <p:messages id="messages" />
```

Code behind

```
public void handleDateSelect(DateSelectEvent event) {
     Date date = event.getDate();
     //Add facesmessage
}
```

I am curious what you need the converter for anyway?  The `value` attribute can be a managed bean property of the `java.util.Date` type without the need for an explicit converter.

Comment: Because of some problem ,I need to user the converter to manualy throw the converter error.